# dynamic range (Index (linest

Tags: excel, indexing

I have been working on a macro for a workstation and I'm stuck now. Basically there is a fairly long simple process to be done and I want it automated to save time and increase accuracy.

The problem is that I am trying to get data points at specific intervals for a data range that changes every time. I can make the formula work for a singular data set but not for data set ranges with more or less.

The formula I'm using is this:

= (((INDEX(LINEST(C2:C4827,B2:B4827 ^{1,2,3}),1))*K2^3) + (((INDEX(LINEST(C2:C4827,B2:B4827 ^{1,2,3}),1,2)))*K2^2) + ((INDEX(LINEST(C2:C4827,B2:B4827 ^{1,2,3}),1,3))*K2) +(INDEX(LINEST(C2:C4827,B2:B4827^{1,2,3}),1,4)))

I need the C2:C4827,B2:B4827 to be dynamic to find the data from B2 and C2 down however far it goes.

Sorry if it's confusing. I've been stuck for a couple days now on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need the C2:C4827,B2:B4827 to be dynamic to find the data from B2
>   and C2 down however far it goes.

You can create a dynamic string that is the data range you want.  Then pass it into the `INDIRECT` formula.  Then assuming "however far it goes" is equal to `COUNTA(...)` of the respective column you can use:

```
=INDIRECT("C2:C"&COUNTA(C:C))
=INDIRECT("B2:B"&COUNTA(B:B))
```

If there is actually *no* data inside `C1` and `B1` just subtract one from the count.

So for your formula it would look like:

```
=(((INDEX(LINEST(INDIRECT("C2:C"&COUNTA(C:C)),INDIRECT("B2:B"&COUNTA(B:B))^{1,2,3}),1))*K2^3) + (((INDEX(LINEST(INDIRECT("C2:C"&COUNTA(C:C)),INDIRECT("B2:B"&COUNTA(B:B))^{1,2,3}),1,2)))*K2^2) + ((INDEX(LINEST(INDIRECT("C2:C"&COUNTA(C:C)),INDIRECT("B2:B"&COUNTA(B:B))^{1,2,3}),1,3))*K2) +(INDEX(LINEST(INDIRECT("C2:C"&COUNTA(C:C)),INDIRECT("B2:B"&COUNTA(B:B))^{1,2,3}),1,4)))
```